# proper javascript usage of "this"

Tags: javascript, json

Which of the following two ways is better to call the Color property and why? Or does it make a difference?

```
lineSymbolizer:{strokeColor: this.Color, strokeWidth: 2, strokeOpacity: 0.7},
```

OR

```
lineSymbolizer:{strokeColor: LatLongLines.Color, strokeWidth: 2, strokeOpacity: 0.7},
```

Context CODE:

```
var LatLongLines = {
    Graticule: null,
    Color: "#000000",
    Show: function () {
        this.Graticule.activate();
    },
    Hide: function () {
        this.Graticule.deactivate()
    },
    Initialize: function () {
        this.Graticule = new OpenLayers.Control.Graticule({
            numPoints: 2,
            labelled: true,
            lineSymbolizer:{strokeColor: this.Color, strokeWidth: 2, strokeOpacity: 0.7},
            labelSymbolizer:{strokeColor: this.Color, strokeWidth: 2, strokeOpacity: 0.7}
        });

        map.addControl(this.Graticule);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd probably stick with `this.Color`.  If you do that, then things would continue to work if you decided someday to clone the "LatLongLines" object.

The Tao of `this` is pretty involved, but it this case it's going to be the contextual object bound from calling the function "through" the "LatLongLines" reference. If those functions might wander away from the original object, then steps would have to be taken to retain a memory of the context object so that it would be correct upon invocation, but that's a complication not evident in anything you've posted.

Comment: +1 It would seem to be technically more efficient as well since it is a direct reference to the object. Using its name would seem to require a proper search through each layer of scoped variables and properties. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

This code won't work as you expect it to.

Your `LatLongLines` is a plain object, but `this` **only** works on `instances`.

```
 obj.method()
    ^----- DOT determines the value of this inside the called function
           If obj is an instance it will be used as 'this' otherwise
           'this' will default to the global 'window' object
```

So either:

- You get rid of all the `this` and use `LatLongLines` instead to have one global object
- Or you create a `LatLongLines` instance, that way `this` will work, you can still go for a singleton (But you know singleton is still global state, and global state is evil)

If you need to create a new instance do something along these lines:

```
function LatLongLines() {
    this.Graticule = null;
    this.Color = "#000000";
};


// Let's use prototypical inheritance, these functions are shared between all 
// LatLongLines instances, of course the this always refers the specific instance that was called
LatLongLines.prototype = {
    Show: function () {
        this.Graticule.activate();
    },

    Hide; function () {
        this.Graticule.deactivate()
    },

    Initialize: function () {
        this.Graticule = new OpenLayers.Control.Graticule({
            numPoints: 2,
            labelled: true,
            lineSymbolizer:{strokeColor: this.Color, strokeWidth: 2, strokeOpacity: 0.7},
            labelSymbolizer:{strokeColor: this.Color, strokeWidth: 2, strokeOpacity: 0.7}
        });

        // Maybe you want to pass map in? :)
        map.addControl(this.Graticule);
    }
};

var someLines = new LatLongLines();
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but I'm not sure what you mean by *`this` only works on instances*. I mean, I guess that's right, but `LatLongLines` *is* referencing an instance. It's just an instance of a plain `Object`. [Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/cpf7C/) Please let me know if I'm totally misinterpreting what you meant.

Comment: both work fine. this.Color and LatLongLines.Color. I'm just wondering which is better. Or if any would be wrong to use.

Comment: Sorry, posting right when coming back from the dentist is a bad idea... yes of course both will work, I'd go with `LatLongLines` though, since this is a single global object, and that would make it more clear, using `this` still implies that there could be multiple of these objects.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, `this` always refers to the item on the left of the dot. In this example you can see the same function scoped to two different `this` objects.

```
myObject = {
    myFunction: function() {
        console.log(this); // in FF or WebKit
    }
};

myObject.myFunction(); // this = myObject

// Now we'll store a reference to our function and call
// it without the dot notation.
myFunc = myObject.myFunction;

myFunc(); // this = window
```

I'd advise using `LatLongLines.Color` if you are unsure of the context of `this` to ensure access to the `Color` property of `LatlongLines`.